# How to use MySQL in Rails with XAMPP in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xampp, mysql2

I have XAMPP and use it to develop my PHP projects. I have also Ruby on Rails on my system, and I want to use MySQL from my XAMPP stack in my Rails projects. I installed the mysql2 gem:

```
sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config="/opt/lampp/bin/" --with-mysql-include="/opt/lampp/include/" --with-mysql-lib="/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/"
```

Also, I tried:

```
bundle update mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config="/opt/lampp/bin/" --with-mysql-include="/opt/lampp/include/" --with-mysql-lib="/opt/lampp/lib/mysql/"
```

But in both the cases I got the following error when I ran `rails s`:

```
/home/sanjib/.rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/sanjib/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: undefined symbol: mysql_server_init
```

Answer (score 0):

First install ruby, ruby on rails and XAMPP. Then, type in your terminal...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
gem install mysql2
```

Before create proyect, create the follow databases in phpmyadmin

appname_development

appname_test

appname_production

Lastly, to create your proyect... type this in your terminal:

rails new appname -d mysql

Reference:[How To Use MySQL with Your Ruby on Rails Application on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04)